# Conditional rendering in react js(Condition inside one more condition)

Tags: reactjs

Actually i'm trying to **hide** and **show** some html elements in **react**.
    I have a created a employee form in which we have multiple partitions for example personal information, contact information etc...
    I created next and previous buttons in form to show and hide other partitions in the form
    There is a partition in which we have education details to fill, so i chose to keep a plus and minus button to add education details using conditions.

```
But finally, my problem is like i have complex conditions on **render** function:

{someCondition && <div>
{anotherCondition && <div></div>}
</div>}

But, i'm getting: *Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag error*. So, what i'm supposed to do?
```

Comment: What does your return block's code look like?

Comment: Sorry bro, i didn't understand your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you gave, I believe you need an enclosing tag like this:

```
//div wraps everything else so the component can render.
<div>
{someCondition && <div>
{anotherCondition && <div></div>
</div>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to wrap them in a div first. Also, your syntax looks a bit wrong (you missed a closing `}`).

```
{someCondition && (
  <div>
    {anotherCondition && <div></div>}
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but the above code is not my original code, i just gave example of my problem.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You must always return one single element enclosing the others.

As regarding conditional rendering, here are some other tips you can consider:

A. for simple conditions, ternary operator is clean enough:

```
return condition ? <p>abc</p> : <p>def</p>
```

B. create rendering functions for cleaner code or more complicated if-else

```
renderButton = () => {
  if (isLoading) { return false }
  if (something) {
    return <div></div>
  } else {
    return <div></div>
  }
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.renderButton }
    </div>
  )
}
```

C. same as above, but without create new functions:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      (()=>{
        if (something) {
          return <div></div>
        } else {
          return <div></div>
        }
      })()
    }
    </div>
  )
}
```